# How to get ReactElement from DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a `ReactElement` rendered for me in the DOM:

```
<form id="form" data-reactid='reactid.1'></form>
```

I can access the `HTMLElement` by doing

```
var element = document.getElementById('form');
element instanceof HTMLElement; // true
// ?? instanceof ReactElement
```

How do I get the `ReactElement` responsible for managing the `form` element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [React - get React component from a child DOM element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462679/react-get-react-component-from-a-child-dom-element)

Comment: Silly answer, but if this is for debugging purposes you could just use the React Chrome extension. If not, ignore me.

Comment: You should never want to do this.  Perhaps you could explain why you want to do this so someone can offer an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

after the component has mounted you can find the element in the DOM via JavaScript as you asked or jQuery or anything els etyhat looks through the DOM.

However you would be probably better off adding a reference to the form and using Reacts internal model to find it quickly / directly, without having to walk the whole DOM to find it.

```
<form ref="myForm" data-reactid='reactid.1'></form>
```

then locate it like this.

```
var form = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myForm);
```