# How to retrieve a react element from a dom element

Tags: reactjs

The question here is not about [is this a good idea or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591223/3361030), because there is a real use-case : I'm scraping a specific website from a headless browser for an internal service and I need to extract data from react.

From an active production application, I would like to retrieve props from the root component using only "pure" JavaScript. The only thing I got is a div right now.

The constraints are:

- It must be done using pure JavaScript (or using standard React lib)
- I cannot add/setup react-devtools extensions or things like that

So far I could always hack into an event handler that I would trigger to manage to enter into React context but I'm looking for cleaner alternatives, any ideas?

Comment: If you explain the real use case, you would get more specific answers. "I wanna do something that I know is not optimal" requires further explanation beyond "believe me, it's a real use case"

Comment: +1. This may be an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and a better answer could be provided with a less abstracted question

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, just so you know: I'm scraping a specific website from a headless browser and need to extract data from react

Comment: Have you tried using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)?

Comment: React is for rendering your code to the browser, if you want to scrape from any websites use some libraries like JSDOM or cheerio.

Comment: @Vikramaditya yes I know JSDOM & cheerio but it's not only for scraping, it's for manipulating an existant UI without access to the source code :)

Comment: @Chris sadly I don't have access to the source code or anything related to it, thus I can't use refs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - getting a component from a DOM element for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321742/react-getting-a-component-from-a-dom-element-for-debugging)