# React.js how to call child component method without using refs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an unusual case. Let say, I have a form. When the user clicks the "save" button I need to trigger a component's method to convert draft.js content to HTML. Normally I just use refs to get access to child and call any method. But in my case draft component is inside  render method of react-router v4 and appears only when URL match pattern. 
This is a hindrance cuz when I define ref

```
<Match pattern={'/info'} render={(props)=> <Draft_Editor ref='editor' />} />
```

parent component doesn't have this 'editor' in refs. What can i do to call method on  from parent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my case. Unfortunate, the solution is using `ref` but it performs it with other approach. Instead of making this `ref='editor'` I did this `ref={(draft) => this.aboutEditor = draft}`. This editor will be available as `this.aboutEditor`.
When i operated with `ref` as string it did't works. But it works fine as callback function.

Answer (score 1):

One way is as follows.

1) Find the DOM node for the parent element using:

```
var parentDOM = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(parentCompInstance);
```

2) Find the DOM node for the child element, using:

```
var childDOM = parentDOM.children[0]; // or something like this, depending on html hierarchy
```

3) Find the React component instance for that child DOM node, using the solution mentioned here: [React - get React component from a child DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462679/react-get-react-component-from-a-child-dom-element/39165212#39165212)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about such an ability of react